# openjdk8 for Android 7.1.2 version

Tags: java, android, ninja

When I compiled the andriod 7.1.2. I encountered this problem. I had checked my openjdk version. It is openjdk8. So, what is another possibility?

```
ninja: error: 'out/host/linux-x86/obj32/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libopenjdkjvm_intermediates/export_includes', needed by 'out/host/linux-x86/obj32/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libopenjdk_intermediates/import_includes', missing and no known rule to make it
```

One solution is from here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/Gz3joT38lVk
Do disable ninja to compile. However, it also has this problem.

So, what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem with deleting and downloading the AOSP again. I suppose that the problem is caused by the multiple and various android version downloading.